# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}$ exists and is finite.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence. Suppose that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists natural number N such that $m \geq n \geq N, | \sum_{k=n}^{m} x_{k}| < \varepsilon$. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}$ exists and is finite. I am told this is a very short proof, but it looks complicated to me and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be *infinite* and not *finite*? Otherwise every convergent series is a counterexample. It is also strange to call a limit existing if it is infinite.

Comment: I suppose this is is a sequence of real or complex numbers? The con conclusion is false. $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ has a finite limit

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. I will edit my question and fix the typo.

Comment: What you have to prove is quite simple indeed: Call $s_n = x_1 + \dots + x_n$: then $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$ exists and is finite whenever $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Now expand the statement "$s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence" and you are done.

Comment: @Crosttul: I'm not sure the O.P. is supposed to know what a Cauchy sequence is.

Comment: @Bernard But is it then still a one-liner?

Comment: Not quite, but it's short. Did the O.P. say it was a one-liner?

Comment: @Bernard No. I read "very short" as one liner when considering Cauchy sequences. Otherwise you have to include the proof that convergent = Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

What does it even mean that a series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ converges? This is defined using sequences. Instead of the complete infinite sum you just consider finite partial sums and then their limit
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k.$$
The left side is the limit of the sequence $y_n:=x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n$. In real analysis it is that a sequence converges *if and only if* it is a Cauchy sequence. This means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ so that for all $n,m>N$ we have $y_m-y_n<\epsilon$. Does this look familiar? It means that

$$\epsilon>y_m-y_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^m x_k. $$

So you are essentially just using the Cauchy property in disguise.